# Eloquent where on relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 models:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   ...
    public function certifications()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Certification', 'certification_user');
    }
    ...
}


class Certification extends Model {
    ...
    public function referential()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Referential');
    }
    ...
}

class Referential extends Model
{
    ...
    public function certifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Certification');
    }
    ...
}
```

I am trying to get all the referentials of the current user certifications.
I could do:

```php
App\User::with("certifications");
```

... and then iterate, but i would rather have a `Collection` of `Referential` objects

I think i should do something like

```php
App\Referential::whereHas("certifications", function($query){
   // something like "where certification in User::certifications()"
});
```

but i can't get it to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested eager loading:

```php
$user = App\User::with('certifications.referential')->first();
$referentials = $user->certifications->pluck('referential');
```

The `whereHas()` query would look like this:

```php
App\Referential::whereHas('certifications.users', function($query) use($user) {
   $query->where('users.id', $user->id);
});
```

Comment: It works great, thank you for your time. The only problem left is that, of course, each referential contains every certifications it has, instead of only the ones that are associated with the user. I should have said that in my question tho. Are you aware of any way to do that?

Comment: Are you referring to the `whereHas()` query?

Comment: What's your code? Something like `$referential->certifications`?

Comment: `$user = Auth::user()::with('certifications.referential')->first();
 $referentials = $user->certifications->pluck('referential')->unique();`
I'm not sure i understand which part of the code you are talking about :/ . My goals is to iterate through `$referential->certifications` which should contains only the certifications present in `$user->certifications`

Comment: `$referential->certifications` works differently than you are excepting. It executes a new query that fetches all the referential's certifications, the query doesn't know about the user. You have to use `Auth::user()->certifications`.

Comment: Ok! Thank you :)